# mac os x byobu vertical split using iTerm, tmux, zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, tmux, iterm2, byobu

How to get vertical split on Mac OS X in byobu?

`Ctrl` + `F2` is not working. It open new window instead of spliting the current.

In oposite spliting horizontaly with `shift` + `F2` works ok.

Comment: I've disabled every control modifier shortcut I can find in the keyboard shortcuts and control+F-keys are still not being sent to the terminal. Most frustrating :/

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in Mac OS Monterey.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use screen escape key to do that:

`Ctrl` + `A` and then `%` for vertical split or `|` for horizontal split.

For whole list: `Ctrl` + `A` and after that `?`.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + F2 is associated to Mac shortcut 'Move focus to the menu bar'.
That might be why it is not working for you.

Comment: Yes, but disabling the Mac shortcut (in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> "Move focus to the menu bar") does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use <kbd>shift</kbd> + the arrow keys.

- <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd> for vertical splits, and
- <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> for horizontal splits.